# How to assign a number on a text cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, file-format, cell-format, numbering

I need help. So I need to assign a number on a txt cell from excel. For example: the cell has the word Blouse. The word Blouse needs to have a value of 20 then I need to multiply this by $5.
How can I assign the Cell with the word Blouse to a corresponding number? I really really need help with this please.
Thank you.

Comment: Your requirement is not very clearly, could you provide the sample about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate table where you enter all your words in one column, then enter all their associated values in the next column.

Then you can use a lookup function like Vlookup or Xlookup to look up the value for the word.

In the screenshot below, the lookup table is in columns F2:G6. You can return the value for "Blouse" with the formula

```
=VLOOKUP("Blouse",$F$2:$G$6,2,FALSE)
```

Since the word "Blouse" is in cell A2, you can also use

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$6,2,FALSE)
```

That will return the value `20`. You can then multiply that by 5, or by the value in cell B2

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$6,2,FALSE)*B2
```

If you want to enter more words into column A, copy the formula down. You need to make sure that all the words you use in column A also exist in the lookup table.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Answer (score -1):

First, enter the value `20` into cell A1 (don't worry about cell placements yet, just refer to end result in bottom-most image to see the finished table).  Then, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, type *including quotes* `"Blouse"`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Then, in cell B1, enter `$5.00`, or change format as needed.  Finally, in cell C1, enter `=A1*B1`.  The end result should appear like as follows in the first column:

[image: Table]